# How to automatically set-up and add functions to a model in R?

Tags: r, function

I am setting up a model, and I am trying to reduce the amount of writing I have to do.

Concretely, I am using the coala R-package to do coalescent simulations, and I am trying to easily implement a stepping-stone migration model.

A reproducible example: 4 linearly distributed populations exchange migrants according to stepping-stone pattern (only the adjacent populations).

```
model <- coal_model(sample_size = c(5, 5, 5, 5),
                    loci_number = 1,
                    loci_length = 10,
                    ploidy = 1) +
feat_mutation(rate = mut_rate, # e.g. 0.1
              model = "HKY",
              base_frequencies = c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25),
              tstv_ratio = 4) +
feat_migration(mig_rate, 1, 2) + # mig_rate can be e.g. 0.5
feat_migration(mig_rate, 2, 1) +
feat_migration(mig_rate, 2, 3) +
feat_migration(mig_rate, 3, 2) +
feat_migration(mig_rate, 3, 4) +
feat_migration(mig_rate, 4, 3) +
sumstat_dna(name = "dna", transformation = identity)
```

This example works, but the downside is that I have to write many 'feat_migration' lines, although there is a clear pattern that could be automated. It is fine for a small number of populations, but I want to do a large simulation with about 70 populations. Does someone has a good idea how to automate this? The documentation has not helped me so far.

I tried two things that didn't work:

```
feat_migration(mig_rate, c(1,2,2,3,3,4), c(2,1,3,2,4,3))
```

and something like this:

```
migration_model <- function(){
  for(i in 1:n_pops){
    feat_migration(mig_rate, i, i+1) +
    feat_migration(mig_rate, i+1, i))
}
```

In the latter case, I don't really know how I can correctly create and parse all functions correctly into my model.

Good ideas are very welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the higher-order functions: `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) and `Reduce` to build a list of function calls and add them iteratively into model. Specifically, `Reduce` helps for function accumulating needs where result of each iteration needs to be passed into the next iteration to reduce to a single final result.

```
n_pops <- 4    
start_pts <- as.vector(sapply(seq(n_pops-1), function(x) c(x, x+1)))  
start_pts
# [1] 1 2 2 3 3 4

end_pts <- as.vector(sapply(seq(n_pops-1), function(x) c(x+1, x)))
end_pts
# [1] 2 1 3 2 4 3

# LIST OF feat_migration()
feats <- Map(function(x, y) feat_migration(mig_rate, x, y), start_pts, end_pts)

# LIST OF FUNCTIONS
funcs <- c(coal_model(sample_size = c(5, 5, 5, 5),
                      loci_number = 1,
                      loci_length = 10,
                      ploidy = 1),
           feat_mutation(rate = mut_rate, # e.g. 0.1
                         model = "HKY",
                         base_frequencies = c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25),
                         tstv_ratio = 4),
           feats,
           sumstat_dna(name = "dna", transformation = identity)
          )

# MODEL CALL     
model <- Reduce(`+`, funcs)
```

---

As an aside, the functional form for `ggplot` `+` calls is `Reduce`:

```
gp <- ggplot(df) + aes_string(x='Time', y='Data') +
        geom_point() + scale_x_datetime(limits=date_range)

# EQUIVALENTLY
gp <- Reduce(ggplot2:::`+.gg`, list(ggplot(df), aes_string(x='Time', y='Data'), 
                                    geom_point(), scale_x_datetime(limits=date_range)))
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems helpful. Some questions/comments: Shouldn't it be `funcs <- list(...)`? It gives an error with `funcs <- c()`. And as `feats` is also a list, it is a list within a list. Doesn't that cause problems? In the current form it doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a slight edit by the solution proposed by Parfait. The model initializes without errors, and can be run in the simulator without errors.

```
n_pops <- 4    
start_pts <- as.vector(sapply(seq(n_pops-1), function(x) c(x, x+1)))  
end_pts <- as.vector(sapply(seq(n_pops-1), function(x) c(x+1, x)))

# LIST OF feat_migration()
feats <- Map(function(x, y) feat_migration(mig_rate, x, y), start_pts, end_pts)

# LIST OF FUNCTIONS
funcs <- c(list(coal_model(sample_size = c(5, 5, 5, 5),
                           loci_number = 1,
                           loci_length = 10,
                           ploidy = 1),
                feat_mutation(rate = mut_rate, # e.g. 0.1
                              model = "HKY",
                              base_frequencies = c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25),
                              tstv_ratio = 4),
                sumstat_dna(name = "dna", transformation = identity)),

            feats)
           )

# MODEL CALL     
model <- Reduce(`+`, funcs)
```